# Angular SEO how to correctly implement dynamic title and meta?

Tags: angular, typescript, seo

I have a little question about Angular title and meta. I have imported libraries into my angular. I set my title and description of meta in the constructor of the .ts files like this (different titles and descriptions for every page of course);

```
//To set the title
this.titleServ.setTitle("SOME TITLE HERE")
//To set the meta
this.meta.addTag({name: "description", content: "SOME DESCRIPTION HERE"})
```

When I run my website through IIS and check from the browser, I still see something like this;

```
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

As said, I cant see my page title or page description from source codes (but I can see it from a google search and at the google chrome tab). I am currently trying to set the search engine optimizations. Is there any problem in here? I mean all the tutorials I have seen can see their page title from the   section and also can see meta.

What did I do wrong or is there anything I need to do more for the website to be visible in google with some keywords search?

Comment: I think any Angular SEO feature requires Server-Side Rendering (with Angular Universal)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I have run the comman "npm i @ng-toolkit/universal" in order to have server-side-rendering, but did I need enything more than just running this command?

Comment: Try doing at least a little research. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular by default is a client-side application. When you serve the app and view the HTML source, you essentially get the source code of `index.html` that's in the root of `src`.

For SEO, you need to render the page *on the server*. That way, when the browser receives the HTML, it is pre-rendered with certain data elements, including the SEO-related tags/content.

This is the official guide on how to add server-side rendering (Angular Universal) to your application: https://angular.io/guide/universal

The key part is, for the server-side rendering to take place, you need to start your app with the dedicated command (e.g. `npm run dev:ssr` by default). This will start up node, which will be handling the requests on the server-side.